# animated popup view similar to one in Ipad music folder

Tags: ipad, popup

I would like to know what is the name of the functionality that is used in the Ipad's Music folder, where when an album folder is clicked, details regarding that album pops up in an animated view.

I tried using presentModelViewController but its functionality is different.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to get sth. like this to work using CoreAnimation / QuartzCore Framework...
be sure to

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

when you want to animate, use CATransform3Dand the poorly documented CATransform3D.m34 property. this will do the **first half** of the animation (assuming 200x200<->450x450 with 180° rotation):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000; // this turns on perspective!
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
someView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
someView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 325, 325);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

for the **second half** of the animation, you have to add/remove your view to the hierarchy. this example shows hiding/showing of a view that already exists as a subview of `someView`, it also makes use of a `BOOL isUp` instance variable (the first half of the aniation is independent of the isUp-flag!)

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {
        if (isUp) {
            someSubView.hidden = YES; // hide subview
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
            CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(someView.layer.transform, -90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            someView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
            someView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            isUp = NO;
        } else {
            someSubView.hidden = NO; // Show subview
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
            CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(someView.layer.transform, 90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            someView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
            someView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 450, 450);

            [UIView commitAnimations];
            isUp = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

one last thing: everything in your view will appear mirrored, it might not be the ideal solution, but mirroring back by applying a `CGAffineTransform` to the subview does the trick:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    someSubView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
    isUp = NO;
}
```

i'm alredy a month late with this solution but i hope it helped someone :)

i first tried using the animateWithDuration:animations:completion: block-based API but that turned out to lag heavily (no smooth first/second-half animaiton even without touching subviews).

Comment: thanks for the answer.. I tried out your code but it is not having any effect for me.. would you be able to explain to me what someView, someSubView and greenView is? I think someView would be my [self.view], my someSubView would be my subview.. but what is greenView?

Comment: when i apply the "first half" animation code u posted to my [self.view], the effect it gives is a imploding effect.. is that what it is?

Comment: sry greenView was a relict of my sample code i used for this post. you can have a look at my test project for this animation - just uploaded it :) [http://cl.ly/3y0c280W1Z1t3G2R0h43](http://cl.ly/3y0c280W1Z1t3G2R0h43)

Comment: would you be able to explain what is happening in the code? in the animate method, the dimensions for green is 325, 325 and after animate did stop its dimensions are 450,450 and the color is red.. where do you make the transformation? Also If I want to do it with just 2 views.. say I have a view with dimensions of 300,300 and when I click a button I add a subview which comes in the same effect say from size 0,0 to size 300,300.. is it possible to do it using ur code?

Comment: also from where is the blue view coming?

Comment: the transformation is done setting the greenView.layer.transform within an animation context (UIView beginAnimation / commitAnimations). I do 2 steps: rotate half and scale half, configure view (show "backside"- show/hide/add/remove views) and rotate and scale further. the blue view comes from XIB and helped me testing the stuff (especially making sure that the top left is where it should and not mirrored somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

On the iPad you have several different options with regards to animating a modal view controller, you can find them here: [UIModalTransitionStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStyle).

However, if you are referring to the "zoom and flip" sort of effect on the album I'm pretty sure this is private behaviour so you would need to develop this yourself.... you might be able to accomplish this with Core Graphics/Quartz.

Comment: @ Jamie.. thanks for the reply.. I already tried out the various styles and none of them satisfied my requirements... also i think that was the word I was looking for "zoom and flip effect".. because it will be easier for me to explain to anyone else what effect I want...